# How to open a new UITableView when clicked on a table cell and add navigation controller dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Basically I add a subview to the main window. This subview has a search bar and a table view. The search bar works and it displays some data on the table view cells. Now when I click on a cell it should load another view with a navigation bar (w/ back button) and a table inside that view. How can this be done? I tried the following code and it doesn't work, it gives me an error saying - "'-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "DetailViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

I tried to set the outlet's in the DetailViewController.nib file but it just wouldn't let me.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[UITableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]];

    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    [navigationController release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you push the detail view controller onto the navigation controller.
I published [a sample code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/MyContacts)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    DetailContactViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailContactViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailContactView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];

}
```